# c# Listitems dont add if exisit in array

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of days (mon, tue, etc..) that I might not want to show, so when I create a list of days, if they are already in the "hiddendays", it doesn't add them.

```
// This would return for example 1, 2
var hDays = account.ScheduleHiddenDays.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

var daySunday = new ViewModels.Day()
{
   Id = 0,
   Name = "Sunday"
};
var dayMonday = new ViewModels.Day()
{
   Id = 1,
   Name = "Monday"
};
var dayTuesday = new ViewModels.Day()
{
   Id = 2,
   Name = "Tueday"
};
var dayWednesday = new ViewModels.Day()
{
   Id = 3,
   Name = "Wednesday"
};
var dayThursday = new ViewModels.Day()
{
   Id = 4,
   Name = "Thursday"
};
var dayFriday = new ViewModels.Day()
{
 Id = 5,
 Name = "Friday"
};
var daySaturday = new ViewModels.Day()
{
 Id = 6,
 Name = "Saturday"
};

// This is where I need to check if they exist in hDays, it doesn't add them to this list. But how?
model.ScheduleHiddenDays = new List<ViewModels.Day>()
{
   daySunday,
   dayMonday,
   dayTuesday,
   dayWednesday,
   dayThursday,
   dayFriday,
   daySaturday
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of this:

```
var days = new List<ViewModels.Day>()
{
 daySunday,
 dayMonday,
 dayTuesday,
 dayWednesday,
 dayThursday,
 dayFriday,
 daySaturday
};

model.ScheduleHiddenDays = days.Where(x => !hDays.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```